# Car gear not engaging

Tags: gears

I received a car from my job and it has been sitting for  3 years it started with no issues when I went to go put it in gear though it would not engage

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine/transmission of the car? Does the engine make any noise when you shift it (change in pitch or rpm)?

Comment: If the car has been standing for 3 years then it needs just about everything checked : tires, brakes, fluids, belts etc

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site :) Which car is it? What engine does it have?

Comment: It is a 2009 Chrysler Town and Country 3.8 engine. The shifter will not move